# Spring integration - less boilerplate?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration

I have started using `Spring-integration` for listening on JMS-queues, and it's working satisfactory, but I have somewhat of an issue with the amount of xml-configuration required in order to set up a listener. Most of this is boilerplate, what changes is really just the jms-instance and the name of the queue to listen to, and the class and method to invoke upon receiving a message. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd">
  <bean id="jms.queue.myQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${myApplication.jms.queue.myQueue}" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="jms.container.myJMSListender"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
        destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="connectionFactory"
              ref="jmsConnectionFactory" /> <!-- Defined elsewhere -->
    <property name="destination"
              ref="jms.queue.myQueue" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted"
              value="true" />
  </bean>

  <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="channel.myQueue" />

  <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="channelAdapter.myQueue"
                                      container="jms.container.myQueue"
                                      channel="channel.myQueue"
                                      acknowledge="transacted"/>

  <int:service-activator id="serviceActivator.myQueue"
                         input-channel="channgel.myQueue"
                         ref="myQueueJMSListener"
                         method="handleMessage" />
</beans>
```

As you can see, a lot of config for something fairly simple, and with quite a lot of JMS-listeners this becomes tedious, both to read and write.

Is there a way to configure listening to a queue with Spring-integration that requires less boilerplate? I've looked into creating my own XML-tag, but I'm kinda hoping that there is a simpler solution.

Comment: You don't have to create the `MessageListenerContainer` instead you can pass the connection factory and destination to the `message-driven-channel-adapter` saves you the listener definition. As described http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-message-driven-channel-adapter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that `Spring integration` has annotation support.

Requires some setup, but this can be used for multiple listeners:

```
  <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsConnectionFactory" brokerURL="${jms.host}">
    <amq:redeliveryPolicy>
      <amq:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0" />
    </amq:redeliveryPolicy>
  </amq:connectionFactory>

  <bean id="cachingJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <jms:annotation-driven />

  <bean id="jmsListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingJmsConnectionFactory" />
  </bean>
```

Then, listening to a certain queue is as simple as:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${myQueueName}")
public void listen(@Payload final String payload) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need an external container if you need to configure properties that are not exposed on the namespace.

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="channelAdapter.myQueue"
                                  destination="jms.queue.myQueue"
                                  connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
                                  channel="channel.myQueue"
                                  acknowledge="transacted"/>
```

Comment: Cool, that helps at least. Using desination-name instead of destination also removes a bit of config, so getting there :)